Changing markdown tasks checkboxes with hotkeys?
Let's say I have markdown tasks like this:
- [ ] Task
- [ ] Task
- [x] Task
- [x] Task

How could I change each task like so below, from any checkbox to any checkbox with hotkeys set for each type (x, -, /, and  ) while the cursor is anywhere on the line?
- [x] Task
- [-] Task
- [ ] Task
- [/] Task


Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the solutions using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

I wrote this lua to do the trick (this is actually the 2nd time so now I installed plugins to auto commit my neovim config!). It works on normal and visual mode.
function substitute(character)
  local firstline = vim.fn.line("v")
  local lastline = vim.fn.line(".")
  if firstline > lastline then firstline, lastline = lastline, firstline end
    vim.cmd(firstline .. "," .. lastline .. "s/\\(^\\s*- \\[\\).\\]/\\1"..character.."\\]")
  end
end

vim.keymap.set({'n', 'v'}, '<leader>t', function() substitute(" ") end, { noremap = true, silent = true })
vim.keymap.set({'n', 'v'}, '<leader>x', function() substitute("x") end, { noremap = true, silent = true })
vim.keymap.set({'n', 'v'}, '<leader>-', function() substitute("-") end, { noremap = true, silent = true })
vim.keymap.set({'n', 'v'}, '<leader>/', function() substitute("\\/") end, { noremap = true, silent = true })


It may be me but I can't bring myself to like the function name substitute when there's both :substitute and substitute() already baked into Vim.

I would probably do something like T[rx or t]rx interactively. To make this more robust for a mapping, we would probably do
nnoremap <leader>x 0f[lrx

since T[ makes some assumptions about our position in the line and where [s are located. The robust version assumes the first [ in the line is a checkbox with a subsequent character to change (empty or not).

You could do:
nnoremap <leader>x <cmd>s/^-\s*\[\zs.\ze\]/x/<CR>
nnoremap <leader>v <cmd>s/^-\s*\[\zs.\ze\]/v/<CR>
nnoremap <leader><space> <cmd>s/^-\s*\[\zs.\ze\]/ /<CR>
" ...

Or a more advanced version:
function! ToggleTick(x)
    let r=winsaveview()
    execute 's/^-\s*\[\zs.\ze\]/' . a:x . '/'
    call winrestview(r)
endfunction

nnoremap <leader>x <cmd>call ToggleTick('x')<CR>
nnoremap <leader>v <cmd>call ToggleTick('v')<CR>
nnoremap <leader><space> <cmd>call ToggleTick(' ')<CR>
" ...

The advanced version restores the position of the cursor and the current search expression using the winrestview() API.
